# How to center any element in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to center `textarea` element, but `margin: 0 auto` doesn't work properly.

Also I tried to wrap element in `div` which has `margin: 0 auto` style.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <textarea rows="4" cols"100"></textare>
</div>
```

Comment: `</textare>` contains a typo and the margin auto only works for block level elements with a set width.

Comment: add `text-align: center` in div style

Comment: thanks I just provide the question in purpose to simplify the job for other developers.. see the answer

Comment: Adding useful self-answered questions is great, but ideally it should only be done on questions that haven't been covered already. See this, or any of the other thousand questions regarding centring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `display: flex` and `justify-content: center;`

```
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
    <textarea rows="4" cols"100"></textare>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center in HTML you can go for:

```
<center>
    <h2>How Not to Center with HTML</h2>
</center>
```

This text may be centered... but you would be better off using CSS to center text or other elements on a web page. Like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
    <p>Some centered text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the div to `display: table;` 
This allows the div to take the width of the textarea instead of taking up `width:100%;`

This should fix it:

```html
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; display:table;">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="100">
    </textarea>
    </div>
```

I also noticed that your question had a few typos and this will not render correct HTML. It should be 'textarea' not 'textare'. Please correct them too and it should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

There is kinda tricky solution:
You should enclose the element inside `wrapper` element, which have `style="text-align: center"` and the element style should be `display: inline-block`

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="100"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: And what about using flexbox?

Comment: @Sfili_81 yes, flexbox is better approach, but this is the simplest way to center element for begginers

Comment: you don't need to add `inline-block` to textarea because it's by default inline-block

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, I appreciate the information provided by you